# How can I get the current systemd log level and change it?

Tags: linux, systemd, logs

I recently came across a situation where I wanted to change my systemd's log level to `debug`, but wanted to make sure I set it back to what it was previously. All my searches related to this only found user service log level settings rather than the actual system log level.

I would like the "get" version of:

```
$ systemd-analyze set-log-level
```

Answer (score 18):

The "get" version is — or rather *was* — since September 2017 (v235), unsurprisingly:

```
systemd-analyze get-log-level
```

But these subcommands were moved from `systemd-analyze` to `systemctl` in November 2019 (v244-rc1), having been combined in January 2018 (v237) into a single subcommand:

```
systemctl log-level
```

## Further reading

- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/ef5a8cb1a7e4529b2b69c4d5a3dcd34e30534f54
- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/90657286fcc2e76a6c76b2c7df6f20f222051c1f
- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/38fcb7f766c84736425e86854b8a4468c126dafa

Comment: On the system (RHEL 7.7) I am on neither of those exist

`# systemd-analyze get-log-level` results in
`Unknown operation 'get-log-level'.` and `# systemctl log-level` results in `Unknown operation 'log-level'.`

Comment: Confirmed that `systemctl log-level` works on OpenSUSE Leap 15.1.

Answer (score 10):

I managed to find the `busctl` command that provides systemd's log level.

#### Example

Current level

```
$ sudo busctl get-property org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
    /org/freedesktop/systemd1 org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager LogLevel
s "info"
```

Override level

```
$ sudo systemd-analyze set-log-level debug
$ sudo busctl get-property org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
    /org/freedesktop/systemd1 org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager LogLevel
s "debug"
```

Comment: FWIW, only `systemd-analyze ..` call was required for me to have busctl one changed to debug.